# getting incorrect values in dataframe while reading data from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am creating dataframe using excel sheet as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = r'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\excel\sheets\Book2.xlsm'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Sheet")
print(df)
```

The columns in this sheet `Sheet` are referenced from another workbook named `Book1`, i.e
when values in columns of Book1 are changed they reflect in `Book2`

but when I print dataframe, older values are shown.

My question is :

1. when we read excel sheet which has columns referenced from another workbook, why the changes are not reflected in dataframe , is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `pandas` will not automatically detect column changes. You'll have to let it know programatically.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: changes should reflect as i am saving the workbook, and then running the code still , older values are shown

Comment: Isn't Excel saving to a shadow copy instead of the original file?

Comment: I think saving to original file...

Comment: @user4599 Sorry your question isn't clear - is your Sheet within Book1 or Book2? What's the direction of data being referenced? Is it Book2 pulling values from Book1's Sheet? Are the values pandas is reading directly from original values themselves or from a Sheet_name!Cell_address type situation?

Comment: @zk-Jack 1) sheet is within Book2.   2) columns from Book1 are referenced in Book2         3) yes,  4) pandas is reading values from Book2 which are of type   like this =[Book2.xlsm]refsheet!$B:$B

Comment: @user4599 and just to narrow the problem down a little more, have all workbooks (Book1 & Book2) been saved with the updated values and closed before running your script?

Comment: @zk-Jack  issue is resolved, actual problem was, that i was reading a wrong file, both files had same name but slightly different paths, values referenced are updating just fine. thanks for your time.